# Laravel named routes not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

Recently I switched to Laravel 5.3.

I have the following route

```
Route::get('/activate/token', 'AccountActivationController@activate')->name('auth.activate');
```

But, when I use

```
dd(route('auth.activate'));
```

I get the following error:

**InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [auth.activate] not defined.**

It works perfectly fine with

```
Route::get('/activate/token', [
    'as' => 'auth.activate',
    'uses' => 'AccountActivationController@activate',
]);
```

Is this new in Laravel 5.3?? I am fairly new to Laravel itself.

Thank You.

Comment: where do you use `dd(route('auth.activate'));` ?

Comment: @hassan I used dd(route('auth.activate')); to debug my code. Didn't really understand why it didn't work. I was following a tutorial where it worked perfectly fine for the tutor.

Comment: you uses it in your route file ? `web.php` ?

Comment: @hassan yes, I am using it in the route file to test

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that comes across this in the future, it is because you aren't refreshing the name lookup on the router.

Laravel 5.2 added the fluent method `name($name)` as a shortcut replacement for `['as' => $name]`, but the `name($name)` method requires `$router->getRoutes()->refreshNameLookups();` to be called at some point after your routes are registered in order to actually complete that mapping internally.

In it's current form, the RoutingServiceProvider implemented in the example `laravel/laravel` package handles this for you behind the scenes, but if you're loading routes in any sort of custom way, you'll need to trigger that refresh yourself at an appropriate time.

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L47-L50 for how it's handled in Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 0):

Missing a tick mark 
Try

```
dd(route('auth.activate'));
```

instead.

Comment: it's a typo, the error does not seems to be a syntax error ;